# PHP - How do I check if a string contains a word?

Tags: php, stripos

Good evening.
I'm making an IRC bot that responds when you mention him. What I want to know is how to make him reply when someone actually says his name. This is what I have so far ($match[3] is the message that someone said on a channel and yes, stripos is because I want it case-insensitive ):

```
if (stripos($match[3], "ircBot") !== false) {
    $isMentioned = true;
}else { $isMentioned = false; }
```

while this does in fact detect if someone said his name, it only works if he's mentioned at the very beginning of the message so for example:

- "ircBot is at the beginning of this sentance" would make $isMentioned true
- "There's ircBot in between this sentance" would make $isMentioned false
- "At the end of this sentance is ircBot" would make $isMentioned false

I want it to return true if "ircBot" is *anywhere* inside $match[3] and not just the beginning

Comment: _“`There's ircBot in between this sentance` would make $isMentioned false”_ – that is just not … well, true: http://3v4l.org/8Efg4

Comment: Update: It actually does respond. Just as long as there isn't a space before ircBot

Comment: That is also not true. The above code will return `true` as long as `ircBot` is _anywhere_ in the subject string – doesn’t matter whether it is at the very start, in between or at the end, and whether or not there are spaces before it. That is simply what `stripos` _does_. You should check what `$match[3]` actually contains, it looks like it might not be what you think it is …

Comment: :HELLOircBot is what it contains when I type "HELLOircBot" into the IRC channel

Comment: That of course yields `true` as well, see http://3v4l.org/tfF2K You are messing something else up here – what that is, no one can possibly tell you with just the lines of code given.

Comment: $data = fgets($irc_connection, 1024); gets the actaul data from the IRC socket. Then $match = explode(" ", $data); seperates it into an array.

Comment: And what does `$data` contain?

Comment: It just echoed. I typed ircBot, : :[user]![user host] PRIVMSG #botTest :ircBot,

Comment: And if you explode that at the space character, then what do you get in `$matches[3]` …? Use `var_dump($matches)` to see what that array contains … then you should realize your mistake. Hint: `explode` takes a third parameter. And next time, do some basic debugging before asking please.

Comment: I just now realized my mistake. I am so sorry for wasting your time on such a stupid thing

Answer (score 1):

You have to look for word boundaries to avoid someone called `MircBot`

```
// using in_array
$isMentioned = in_array('ircbot', preg_split('/\s+/', mb_strtolower($match[3])));

// using regex word boundaries
$isMentioned = preg_match('/\b(ircBot)\b/i', $match[3]);
```

http://3v4l.org/lh3JT

Comment: In neither of these ircBot responds even when it's at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Use [`stristr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) instead

```
if (stristr($match[3], "ircBot") !== false) {
    $isMentioned = true;
}else { $isMentioned = false; }
```

Comment: Still only shows when a sentence starts with ircBot

Comment: stristr will return the substring when it matches and false when the string doesn't exist. Whether it's at the front, middle, or end of the string your searching.

Comment: I does. Just as long as there isn't a space before ircBot. Example: 6ircBot returns true but 6 ircBot doesn't

Comment: I just tested this with the string 'this is my ircBot' and it came back true.

Comment: Weird. Well, what I'm doing is sending the message directly into the socket. What I did is first tell it to echo $match[3] to see if something was going on. :HELLOircBot was the output. Could the : be interfering something?

Comment: Nope, it would match `someircBotstring` and it would match `this is my ircBot` ... as long as it's in the string.

Comment: Well, when I type "Hi ircBot!" into the IRC channel he doesn't say anything. But when I type "ircBot, hello!" he says "Hi, user!"

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is somewhere else, e.g. the construction of $match[3].  This works fine:

```
$isMentioned = stripos('This is in the middle of ircBot the string','ircbot') !== false;
echo( $isMentioned ? 'Is Mentioned' : 'Sad ignored bot');
```